# Why doesn't this sass mixin with pseudo selectors work?

Tags: css, sass

Why doesn't this work:

```
@mixin link($props) {
  &:link,
  &:visited { $props };
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> Invalid CSS after "...sited { $props ": expected ":", was "};"

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is a bit off is a couple of places, try something like:

```
@mixin link ($props) {
 &:hover,
 &:visited { color: $props; }
}
```

Where the 'color' could be any css rule.
I feel that this article has a few good sass mixin examples for reference: http://zerosixthree.se/8-sass-mixins-you-must-have-in-your-toolbox/

Comment: What if I want to do more than just color? Like...

    @include link(color: #fff; background: #000;);

Comment: @mixin link ($color, $bgcolor) {
 &:hover,
 &:visited { color: $props; background: $bgcolor}
}

Comment: What if I wanted to do way more than that without having to specify more vars? 

`@include link(display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px; color: #fff; background: url(awesome.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 / contain;);`

I think it would be way more flexible if a mixin could do this.

Comment: yup,  all that. You can do it. Again, check out that link I posted above for reference.

Comment: Actually, looking at the duplicate question from cimmanon above led me to use `@content` instead of using the parameter `$props`. It's like using arguments in javascript instead of params: `@mixin link {
  &:link,
  &:visited { @content };
}`